# how to auto populate txt from ducusign_rest gem

Tags: ruby, docusignapi

I am trying to use 'docusign_rest'(https://github.com/jondkinney/docusign_rest) gem to create envelope from template.

I have uploaded the file and defined txt field with data label on document thru Docusign Console.

How can I use this gem to pass data to document and display?

Not sure this approach "Creating an envelope from a template using custom tabs" is the right way to develop system.

Comment: I think you custom fields but I'm not sure. I'm guessing I could rephrase your question as: "How can I populate custom fields of an envelope when uploading a document to DocuSign with docusign_rest"

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically pass data to an envelope that uses a template by using the composite templates feature of the Envelopes::create API call.

Or you can skip the template step and create fields (tabs) directly on the document when you create the envelope. In this case, you can supply `values` for the tabs when you create them.

You may want to use the [official DocuSign SDK for Ruby.](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client)